# Unable to print value from inside array

Tags: python, arrays, object

I have an array in which has multiple objects inside it, I want to parse it to give me the value of `bar` that is in each object.

This is a mock of the array/object I am trying to parse to get the values from.

```
[
{
  foo: [
    {
       bar: 50,
       crow: true
    }
  ]
}
...
{}
...
]
```

So far this is as far as I have come on the code and admittedly it isn't very far as I've been back tracking as things go wrong and worse.

```
for foo in response:
    print foo
    foo_list = list(foo)
    print(foo_list[0])
```

This outputs the whole value of `foo` then it outputs only the key `foo`

PS I know this is a repeat question, please only mark as so if the repeat one has the exact format I am looking for.

Comment: So you have a list of dictionaries whose values are lists of dictionaries? If so, calling such a structure an array is a bit misleading.

Comment: @JohnColeman What is a dictionary? I come from the JS world not python, to me in JS what I'm seeing it looks like an array. The `response` in my code snippet in the OP is JSON

Comment: `{'bar':50, 'crow': True}` is an example of a dictionary. For `json`, it is probably better to use the standard module for `json` than trying to parse it on your own.

Answer (score 2):

You want something along the lines of

```
something[0]['foo'][0]['bar']
```

The '[' means you need to access an element of a list. The [0] gets the first element of a list.
The '{' means you need to access an entry of a dictionary. The ['foo'] means get the value of key 'foo'.
Your sample above has a dict in a list in a dict in a list.

You should also not scrimp when it comes to error checking... The above could easily be:

```
sentinel = object() # unique object for checking default from get()
bar = None
if isinstance(something, list) and len(something) == 1:
    elem = something[0]
    if isinstance(elem, dict):
        val = elem.get('foo', sentinel)
        if val is not sentinel: 
          # and so on and so on...
```

The other thing to mention is that sometimes you don't care about the name of the key. Instead of saying `dick.get(key)`, which requires knowing the key, you can say `dick.values()[0]`

So, the top could also be:

```
something[0].values()[0][0].values()[0]
```

Again, don't skimp on the error checking...

Comment: That's kind of what I figured however could not for the life of me get it to work

Comment: Anything of the sort of that outputs just `0`

Comment: @JoshKirby this answer works with what you have shown. If it doesn't work with your actual data, then you should edit your question so that it better reflects the structure of your actual data.

Comment: @JohnColeman I can't post all my data, this does not work for what I have. I have provided as close to my actual data as I can, ie company would fire me if I posted private info

Comment: @JoshKirby You can still do the effort of mocking up a [mcve] which others can run and which adequately reproduces the essence of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you want the inner values. Try this code:

```
response = [{'foo': [ { 'bar': 50, 'crow': True } ] }]

for i in range(len(response)):
    for key in response[i].keys():
        for d in response[i][key]:
            print(list(d.values()))
```

Basically, what's happening here is we're first iterating through the outer list (`[]`), then iterating the keys in that array, then iterating each item in that value list for key `foo`, then printing a list of the dictionary's values. You could also just grab the whole dict as `d`.

Also, if this is JSON, you're going to want to parse it first with the `json` lib. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html for more information on that.